# How to evaluate a PHP expression without using eval()

Tags: php, arrays, variables, eval

I want to display a variable or an array by passing the variable name to a function and display it without having to use the **dangerous** `eval()` function. I am having trouble making it happen. Is it possible to do?

Here's the code:

```
show( '$_SESSION', 'a' ); // it does not work
show( '_SESSION', 'a' ); // it does not work

function show( $showWhat = null, $showType = null ) {
  echo '<pre>';
  if( strtolower( $showType ) == 'a' ) { // 'a' represents array()'s
    print_r( '$' . $showWhat ); // it does not work
    print_r( $showWhat ); // it does not work
  }
  else { // 'v' represents variables
    echo $showWhat;
  }
  echo '</pre>';
  exit;
}
```

Comment: `eval()` isn't dangerous if you know how to use it.

Comment: touche -- that's why I put in quotes

Comment: You can drop the `$showType ` part if you use `is_array($showWhat)`

Comment: You can try `var_dump()`

Comment: Thanks @Fluinc. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Well, var_dump() does not work either. I am thinking that this is not possible to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trials and tests I got it to work this way:

```
show( $_SESSION );

/**
  * halts processing and displays arrays & variables
  */
  function show( $showWhat = null ) {

    echo '<pre>';

    if( is_array( $showWhat ) ) {
      echo 'Array: ';
      print_r( $showWhat );
    }
    else {
      echo 'Variable: ';
      echo $showWhat;
    }

    echo '</pre>';
    exit;

  } /* show() */
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `eval` at all.

Call function like this

```
show( '_SESSION', 'a' );
```

This will work

```
print_r( $$showWhat );
```

**Full code:**

```
    show( '_SESSION', 'a' );

    function show( $showWhat = null, $showType = null ) {
      echo '<pre>';
      if( strtolower( $showType ) == 'a' ) { // 'a' represents array()'s
        print_r( $$showWhat ); // it does work
      }
      else { // 'v' represents variables
        echo $showWhat;
      }
      echo '</pre>';
      exit;
    }
```

**Update:**

For the super global variables `(SESSION, SERVER etc)` you should use `global` keyword.

```
$context = '_SESSION';
global $$context;
if(isset($$context)) {
    print_R($$context);
}
```

Comment: ah, overlooked that method...thanks @Parixit. I'll give it a shot and post back.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't format the output from `print_r();`. You'll need a recursive function which runs through the array in order to create "proper" html

Comment: @YUNOWORK I just modified function as it is. No need to format `HTML` here.

Comment: @H.Ferrence You are using this for super global variables. Please check my update.